# jquery setInterval conflict with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

i have one setinterval method which call php script every 3 sec to check for new data.

```
                    setInterval($.proxy(function(){
                    var dataString =  options.url+'table_id='+options.table_id
                    $.ajax({
                            type : 'POST', 
                            url : options.url+"check", 
                            data : dataString, 
                            success: $.proxy(function(data){
                            if(data != ""){
                            var json = $.parseJSON(data);

                            if(json.num >= 1){
                                this.callOtherMethod(json.user_id);

                                    }, this));
                            }
                        }
                            }, this)
                        });
                }, this), 3000);
```

if num is >= 1 button will be displayed.

and if user click on add button the url from callOtherMethod loads so many times as the first method is called.
example:
if the user click on add button after 30 sec 
example.com/add will be called 10 times.

my callOtherMethod

```
                this.callOtherMethod = function(id)
                {
                this.id = id;
                $('#button').show();
                $(".add").bind('click', $.proxy(function(){
                if(this.user_id > 0){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "add",
                        data: options.url+"text="+this.text+"&user_id="+this.user_id,
                        success: $.proxy(function(data){
                            if(data != ""){

                            // add action
                            }                                
                        }, this)
                    });
                }
                },this));
```

thank you for any help

Comment: what is the problem your facing exactly?

Comment: the problem is when user clicks on the add button after 30 sec the new request from the method callothermethod will be called 10 times and i have 10 inserts in my db :)

Comment: $.proxy feels like spaghetti code. Could you edit to improve indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are showing the button and doing the bind in the `callOtherMethod` while you should only be assigning your new `id`. The `$('#button').show()` and  `$(".add").bind('click', $.proxy(function(){ ...` should be called in a separate method that fires only once from the `setInterval` method. (you can use and a check a boolean var to make it fire only once).

hope this helps

Comment: no problem! you need to click the checkmark next to the answer to close it though :) thanks.